# Does Solace block and remove mind control effects?

Tags: xcom-2

In *XCOM 2*, psi soldiers can learn an ability called "Solace", which is supposed to block and remove negative mental effects, presumably like panic, disorientation, and stun.

Does Solace also block and remove mind control effects? If one of my soldiers has been mind controlled, can I simply move a psi soldier with Solace into range to immediately remove the effect?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it myself, but according to the script powering Solace: yes, it will. Solace will prevent or remove the following statuses:

- Disoriented (as from Mindspin or a flashbang)
- Confused (not sure what this is, it may not actually be used in the game)
- Panicked (as from a mental attack or from seeing a soldier die, being injured, etc.)
- Stunned (as from any one of a bunch of stun effects)
- Mind Control (as from Sectoids)

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that moving a psi with this ability next to a debuffed soldier will remove the debuff. One of my guys was mind controlled by an avatar in the final battle, and moving my psi next to him removed the MC.